# Pygame always showing a black screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to recreate [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AY9MnQ4x3zk) pygame but i keep getting a black screen without anything displayed. I get no error's so i don't know where i need to start.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Runner")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

test_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/Sky.png')

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.blit(test_surface,(0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code. The problem is not reproducible.

Comment: The code is running correctly and I think you need to make sure from your `png` file!

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved after reinstalling python and pycharm. Not sure if both were needed but it did the trick for me, thanks all.

Comment: for future reference, it was neither Python's nor PyCharm's fault